# How to add the image label in Reddit share?

Tags: javascript, social-networking, reddit

Hi All I integrated the Reddit sharing in my project.

While going to the Reddit share page *image share* option shown below is not coming.

I need that option along with other existing option as shown below.

Can anyone give an idea how can I fix this one.

[image]

Comment: That's a relatively new field. Linking an image will automatically use that image as a thumbnail. If you're linking a page, reddit will attempt to use Opengraph.

Comment: @student-17: if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted

Comment: I tried that but not solved the issue @KarolKlepacki

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill out meta tags, compatible with Open Graph Protocol. Read more on their website: http://ogp.me/

Sample code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: @Gant fixed this :)